# Redirect to new record after being created

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components

I'm new with all of this so please be gentle :) So...I've got a **lightning:recordForm** that I'm using to create a new record. After I hit save I would like to be redirected to the newly created record.

Here's my cmp:

```
<aura:component controller="text_card_r" implements="force:hasRecordId,force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
        <aura:attribute name="projects" type="List"/>   
        <aura:attribute name="employees" type="List"/>
        <aura:attribute name="employeesProjects" type="List"/>
        <aura:attribute name="isModalOpen" type="boolean" default="false"/>
        <lightning:notificationsLibrary aura:id="notifLib"/>
        <lightning:navigation aura:id="navService"/>    
        <!-- beginning card do header-->
        <lightning:card variant="Narrow" title="Projects Cards" iconName="standard:record" >
                <aura:set attribute="actions">
                    <lightning:button label="New" onclick="{! c.openModel }"/>
                </aura:set>            
        </lightning:card>        
      <!-- end card do header-->            

    <!-- beginning modal-->
    <div class="slds-m-around_xx-large">
        <!--Use aura:if tag to display/hide popup based on isModalOpen value-->  
        <aura:if isTrue="{!v.isModalOpen}">

            <!-- Modal/Popup Box starts here-->
            <section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modal-heading-01" aria-modal="true" aria-describedby="modal-content-id-1" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open">
                <div class="slds-modal__container">
                    <!-- Modal/Popup Box Header Starts here-->
                    <header class="slds-modal__header">
                        <h3 id="modal-heading-01" class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-hyphenate">New Project</h3>
                    </header>
                    <!--Modal/Popup Box Body Starts here-->
                    <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium" id="modal-content-id-1">
                        <lightning:recordForm

                            objectApiName="Project__c"                            
                            layoutType="Full" 
                            mode="edit"                             
                            onsuccess="{!c.handleSuccess}" 
                            oncancel="{!c.closeModel}"/>

                    </div>
                    <!--Modal/Popup Box Footer Starts here-->
                </div>
            </section>
            <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open"></div>
        </aura:if>
    </div>
```

And here's my handleSuccess in the controller:

```
handleSuccess: function(component, event, helper) {
    var params = event.getParams();
    component.find("navService").navigate({
        "type": "standard__recordPage",
        "attributes": {
            "recordId": params.response.id,
            "objectApiName": "Project__c",
            "actionName": "view"
        }
    });
    component.set("v.isModalOpen", false);
}
```

Its not working. The record gets created but it prompts a popup message error  instead of redirecting it to the new record.

> [NoErrorObjectAvailable] Script error.
>   a()@https://static.lightning.force.com/eu29/auraFW/javascript/5EkiQjrG-amda9Z1-HgsDQ/aura_prod.js:936:169
>   {anonymous}()@https://static.lightning.force.com/eu29/auraFW/javascript/5EkiQjrG-amda9Z1-HgsDQ/aura_prod.js:936:362
>   v.dispatchEvent()@https://static.lightning.force.com/eu29/auraFW/javascript/5EkiQjrG-amda9Z1-HgsDQ/aura_prod.js:4:25839
>   v.handleSuccess()@https://coee-management-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/components/lightning/recordForm.js:2:8296
>   o.createOrSaveRecord.then._pendingAction()@https://coee-management-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/components/interop/recordEditForm.js:2:7050

Could you please help me?

Comment: What error are you receiving?

Comment: @JayantDas, check it out here: https://pastebin.com/4Dype622

Comment: Can you [edit your question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/307262/edit) to add that detail?

Comment: Yep. Will do it.

Comment: I think Jayant was asking you to provide the text of the error message _here_, on _this site_ rather than keeping it as a link (which will eventually expire). The more hoops you make people jump through, even if they're easy, the less likely they are to help. Having the error message here also helps give context to the question so that other people with similar problems can say "hey, that looks like the problem I'm having, I wonder if one of the answers will help me".

Comment: @DerekF you're absolutely right. Done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If You want to just redirect to particular record detail page then use below code

```
var navEvt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
    navEvt.setParams({
      "recordId": "00QB0000000ybNX",
      "slideDevName": "Detail"
    });
    navEvt.fire();
```

Please refer https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:navigateToSObject/documentation

Comment: Thanks! And how can i get the recordId of the recently created object from the recordForm?

Comment: Please use event.getParam("id")

Comment: handleSuccess : function (component, event, helper){
  var payload = event.getParams("id"); 
  var navEvt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
  navEvt.setParams({
    "recordId": payload.id, 
    "slideDevName": "Detail"
  });
  navEvt.fire();
 }

it works!