I'm not able to redirect account record page using lightning aura component
<aura:component controller="auraaccountController" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:appHostable,force:lightningQuickAction,lightning:hasPageReference">
    <aura:attribute name="accountName" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="accountIndustry" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="accountRevenue" type="Decimal" />
    <aura:attribute name="errorMessage" type="String" />
    
     <lightning:navigation aura:id="navService"/>

    <lightning:card title="Create New Account" class="slds-p-around_medium">
        <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
            <lightning:input label="Name" value="{!v.accountName}" required="true" />
            <lightning:input label="Industry" value="{!v.accountIndustry}" />
            <lightning:input label="Annual Revenue" value="{!v.accountRevenue}" type="number" />
            <lightning:button label="Create Account" onclick="{!c.createAccount}" variant="success" class="slds-m-top_medium" />
            <aura:if isTrue="{!v.errorMessage}">
                <div class="slds-text-color_error slds-m-top_medium">{!v.errorMessage}</div>
            </aura:if>
        </div>
    </lightning:card>
</aura:component>

({
    createAccount: function(component, event, helper) {
        var action = component.get("c.saveAccount");
        action.setParams({
            name: component.get("v.accountName"),
            industry: component.get("v.accountIndustry"),
            annualRevenue: component.get("v.accountRevenue")
        });

        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                // Handle success - you can show a success message or redirect the user
                var newAccount = response.getReturnValue();
                alert('Account created successfully: ' + newAccount.Name);
               
                // Redirect to the new account's record page
                var navService = component.find("navService");
                var pageReference = {
                    type: 'standard__recordPage',
                    attributes: {
                        recordId: newAccount.Id,
                        objectApiName: 'Account',
                        actionName: 'view'
                    }
                };
                navService.navigate(pageReference);
               
                alert('Redirected to account detail page' + newAccount.Id);
                
                
                
            } else {
                // Handle error
                var errors = response.getError();
                var message = "Unknown error"; // Default error message
                if (errors && Array.isArray(errors) && errors.length > 0) {
                    message = errors[0].message;
                }
                component.set("v.errorMessage", message);
            }
        });
        
        
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})

I have created a simple Lightning Aura component for creating an account. The issue is that when the account record is created successfully, it does not redirect to the account record page. What can be done to resolve this?

Check below https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/307262/redirect-to-new-record-after-being-created
